# Форма заполнения отправки сообщения

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть кнопка отправки сообщения. Как мне сделать, чтобы при клике на "отправить сообщение" появлялась, например, как в контакте, форма заполнения отправки сообщения. 
У меня есть код

```
<form action='post.php' method='post'>
    <br>
    <textarea cols='43' rows='4' name='text'></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$myrow[login]'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$myrow[id]'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Comment: спс     .     .  .

Answer (score 1):

На javascript написать функцию, которая меняет видимость формы.
Видимость указывается в css.
Проще всего по-моему определить два класса в стилях и в функции менять класс элемента. 
Адрес ссылки должен быть вида `href="javascript:show_form()"` или можно через параметр `onclick="show_form()"`, тогда обычно пишут `href="#"`.

Пример с сайта http://on-line-teaching.com/js/js.layers.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function toggleInformer()   
    {       
        // ищем нужный нам тег информера
        var elm = document.getElementById("informer");

        // если тег найден, обрабатываем его
        if(elm)
        {
            // меняем видимость элемента на противоположную
            if(elm.style.visibility == "visible")
            {
                elm.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            else
            {
                elm.style.visibility = "visible";
            }

        }   
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="toggleInformer(); return false;"> 
 Информер 
</a>
<div id="informer" style="border:1px solid red; color: green;visibility:visible;" >
 Содержимое информера   
</div>
```

Comment: Как-то так: http://on-line-teaching.com/js/js.layers.htm
попробуйте самый первый блок кода, дальше там слишком сложно

Comment: Что ж вы и себя, и других мучаете? )) Что-то за последние два дня, часто начал вспоминать Попова. Аж запереживал - уж не случилось ли с ним чего ))) Судя по вашему коду, вы очередная его жертва, поэтому не майтесь (*цензура*) и начните изучать с нуля и HTML, и CSS, PHP с MySQL из достойных источников ;)

Comment: Вот вам блок вставил сюда

Comment: спс всё робит